# How to define the order status after placing it for a virtual product in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, order-status

When I place an order, Mangento2 sets it into STATE = 'complete' and STATUS = 'complete'. However I still need to process the order in some way. I want it to be set to STATE_NEW or in some way pending. Also, the order is charged online using the payment method.

I have made more research. My product type is virtual so Magento2 recognizes that all paid virtual products should be complete. I chose virtual product as I am selling services. So no shipping information is needed.

Comment: What Payment Method are you using?

Comment: I am using a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign the New Order Status in the config settings of your Payment method unless your Payment Method doesn't have a config for Order Status.

*Admin Path:*

`Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods`